# Openmp with a function call and nested loop

Tags: openmp

I am trying to parallelize my code with openMP, it has function call, nested loop, and dependency.....how can i do it?

```
for (int i = 2; i <=1001; i++) {

   for ( k=(i-1)*600;k<i*600;k++){
    v_verlet(dt);

    for(int s=0;s<2;s++)
    array[k-600][s]=v[50][s]; 

    sum1+=total_energy();
    sum2+=temperature();
    if (k % up_interval == 0) {
        updatepairlist();
        updatePairSeparations();
                               }
    if( k%15000==0)
     {
      sum1/=15000;
      sum2/=15000;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on which type of parallelization do you want to perform (a task decomposition, a data decomposition...), but this is not the only thing. There are many things to keep in mind. It all relies on how you have written your code, what you are looking to achieve, etc.

In this code, we could use a collapse clause that encapsulates the iterations of n loops. If we focus on how we assign tasks to threads, we could also decide if assigning them statically or dinamically (do we previously know the amount of threads we will use and the workload distribution among threads? Then, would it be more efficient to assign tasks in compilation time and avoiding task assignation during execution time?). What about protecting the accesses to sum1 and sum2 or other variables with an atomic clause (that would be necessary or not, depending on whether the original variables are being used by all threads or not)?

Look at the third for loop, suppose that you have a very large vector and you access it multiple times, you could consider avoiding false sharing by using a padding strategy, which ensures less cache misses and miss penalties by converting a vector in a bidimensional array which is adapted to the size of one line of our cache.

I suggest you to try more examples by searching on the internet.

Hope this helped, have fun!